# DynamoDb Update item conditional-expression function attribute-not-exists does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

i am using AWS DynamoDb update-item API in bash where I have this use case where I need not to update the bool value for the attribute when the attribute with the same name already exists. Hence i am using the conditional expression with the attribute_not_exists function. But it does not work even though my table has the attribute with the name I just created using the same API. instead, it just updates it with a new value.

below is my code in bash

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
        --region us-east1 \
        --table-name TABLE_NAME \
        --key '{"settingName":{"S":"'"$ATTRIBUTE_KEY"'"}}' \
        --update-expression 'SET #VAL = :val' \
        --expression-attribute-names '{"#VAL":"settingValue"}' \
        --expression-attribute-values '{":val":{"'"$DATA_TYPE"'":'$ATTRIBUTE_VALUE'}}' \
        --condition-expression "attribute_not_exists($ATTRIBUTE_KEY)" \
        --return-values ALL_NEW
```

Comment: `attribute_not_exists` vs `attribute_exists`

Comment: My bad, it was written initially as attribute_not_exists. I updated the condition expression. It doesn't seem to work either @hoangdv

Comment: Can you share specifically what is your issue and result the command is returning? And also check your typo errors for example the region that is `us-east-1` and not `us-east1`